# how to plot data with samples that die off?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am bench-marking the effectiveness of a program that runs until it finds a solution and trying to create charts to show how the program tends to go about finding the solution. the program sometimes takes 500 attempts and sometimes takes 2000, I can show that they both steadily produced better and better answers until they find the target. I have hundreds of runs to examine so I would like to see how the average of all of the runs moves over time, however, numpy does not allow me to average data of different lengths. How can I get it to just average the data points that are available at each test number.

EX: trial1 = [33.4853, 32.3958, 30.2859, 33.2958, 30.1049, 29.3209]

trial2 = [45.2937, 44.2983, 42.2839, 42.1394, 41.2938, 39.2936, 38.1826, 36.2483, 39.2632, 37.1827, 35.9936, 32.4837, 31.5599, 29.3209]

BE = numpy.array([trial1, trial2])

BEave = numpy.average(BE, axis=0)

I would like to get back: BEave = [39.3895, 38.34705, 36.2849, 37.7176, 35.69935, 34.30725, 38.1826, 36.2483, 39.2632, 37.1827, 35.9936, 32.4837, 31.5599, 29.3209]]

Comment: you have typos and errors in your example. Can you fix them?

Comment: It's not clear what the average over two arrays of different length would actually be. Can you provide an easy example **together with the expected output**?

Comment: from your problem statement data sizes it doesn't seem like numpy is needed - a list of (variable length) lists should be fine

Comment: @jacoblaw, I think I fixed it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have added the answer I would hope to get. basically I want it to average everything that exists at the point in the list. so with trial 2 being longer then trial 1 the end should just be trial 2 because it is averaged with itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a large array of nans and fill in the trials up the respective maximum number of trials. The rest of the array row will stay `nan`. Then take the mean along the vertical axis, using [`numpy.nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

trial1 = [33.4853, 32.3958, 30.2859, 33.2958, 30.1049, 29.3209]

trial2 = [45.2937, 44.2983, 42.2839, 42.1394, 41.2938, 39.2936, 38.1826, 
          36.2483, 39.2632, 37.1827, 35.9936, 32.4837, 31.5599, 29.3209]

m= np.max([len(trial1), len(trial2)])

# create array of nans
BE = np.ones( (2, m) )*np.nan 
# fill it with trials up to the number of trial values
BE[0,:len(trial1)] = trial1
BE[1,:len(trial2)] = trial2

# nanmean = take mean, ignore nans
BEave = np.nanmean(BE, axis=0)

plt.plot(trial1, label="trial1", color="mediumpurple")
plt.plot(trial2, label="trial2", color="violet")
plt.plot(BEave, color="crimson", label="avg")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a way to get the best and worst from each step? I would like to be able to show best, worst, and average on the graph.

Comment: If by "best" and "worst" you mean the minimum and maximum, numpy also has `nanmin` and `nanmax` methods.